# How to test a react component after fecthing data from useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, jestjs, enzyme

In my TestComponent.jsx, I am fecthing data from axios in useEffect and setting the state.After data fetch, mapping through the data and adding child component to it.
I am trying to test the same behaviour in my testcase and failing to assert that child component is added to the component.

My test component is

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

const baseURL = "https://shorturl.at/mA179";

export default function TestComponent() {
  const [posts, setPost] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(baseURL).then((response) => {
      setPost(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!posts) return null;
const postsDiv=  posts.map((post,i)=>{
  <div key={i} className="display">
  <h1>{post.title}</h1>
  <p>{post.body}</p>
</div>});

  return    <>{postsDiv}</>
 
}
```

and my Testcase is

```
import React from "react";
import enzyme, { shallow,mount } from "enzyme";
import axios from "axios";
import TestComponent from "./TestComponent";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

describe("TestComponent", () => {
   
  enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

   

    test("should display the string returned from the get function", async () => {
        const posts = [
            {
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
                "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
              },
              {
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 2,
                "title": "qui est esse",
                "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
              },
          ];
          const baseURL = "https://shorturl.at/mA179";
          jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockImplementation((baseURL) => {
     
          return Promise.resolve({ data: posts });
      
    });

          const wrapper = mount(<TestComponent></TestComponent>);
          
        const displayDivBeforeClick = wrapper.find(".display");
        expect(displayDivBeforeClick.exists()).toBe(false);

        await Promise.resolve();
        const displayDivAfterClick = wrapper.find(".display");
        console.log(wrapper.debug())
        return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve)).then(() => {
            const displayDivAfterClick = wrapper.find(".display");
            console.log(wrapper.debug())
            wrapper.debug();
            expect(displayDivAfterClick.exists()).toBe(true);
        });
    });

  
});
```

and I am getting this below error:

```
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:545
      Warning: An update to TestComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

      When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

      act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
      
      This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at fb.me/react-wrap-tests-with-act
          in TestComponent (created by WrapperComponent)
          in WrapperComponent
    console.log src/TestComponent.enz.test.tsx:42
      <TestComponent />
    console.log src/TestComponent.enz.test.tsx:45
      <TestComponent />

  ● TestComponent › should display the string returned from the get function
                                                                                                                                                                     
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                     
    Expected: true                                                                                                                                                   
    Received: false                                                                                                                                                  

      45 |             console.log(wrapper.debug())
      46 |             wrapper.debug();
    > 47 |             expect(displayDivAfterClick.exists()).toBe(true);
         |                                                   ^
      48 |         });
      49 |     });
      50 |

      at toBe (src/TestComponent.enz.test.tsx:47:51)
'''
Stuck in this tc from a week. I can see tat there are many posts in stackoverflow for the same issue, but none got answer.

Thanks in advance.
```